# Problema Report viewer vs 2017

Tags: c#

Tengo un problema soy nuevo en esto, tengo un proyecto y le agregue el paquete Reportviewer.winforms, agregue el Report viewer en un windows forms y al momento de ejecutar el formulario pues me marca el siguiente error:

Se ha producido un error durante el procesamiento local de informes La definición del informe "no es válida Error inesperado al procesar los informes.

Se produjo una excepción en el inicializador de tipo de Microsoft Reporting Services Report intermediate Format Persistence Intermediate Format Version

La ruta de acceso no tiene un formato válido.